# default layout handle for order item grid NOT display in custom email magento ce1.7.0.2

Tags: email, magento-1.7

trying to send email programmaticaly with order items grid using `{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}` but its not working. `{{htmlescape var=$order.getCustomerName()}}` show customer name properly.

what is missing?

following is code for email and 29 is id of template in which `{{layout handle="sales_email_order_items" order=$order}}` is mentioned.

```
Mage::app()->getLocale()->emulate($storeId);
$SalesOrder = Mage::getModel("sales/order")->load($requestParams['order_id']);
$storeEmail = Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom1/email');
$storeName =  Mage::getStoreConfig('trans_email/ident_custom1/name');
$recvEmail = $CustomerName;
$recvName =  $email;
$templateId = 29;
//set data to use in array
$edata['comment'] = $ResultData->URL;
$edata['order'] = $SalesOrder;
//Core email sending code
$emailTemplate = Mage::getModel('core/email_template')->
                    addBcc('abc@example.com')->
                    sendTransactional($templateId);
$emailTemplate->getProcessedTemplate($edata);
$emailTemplate->setSenderEmail($storeEmail);
$emailTemplate->setSenderName($storeName);
$emailTemplate->setType('html');
$emailTemplate->send($recvEmail,$recvName,$edata);
```

Thanks in advance.

Note: If you know any good tutorial on sending email programmatically with ordered item grid. please tell me.

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar issue also but after much research i got it fixed. You can include the block and template on the email template. Here is an example below.

*{{block type="sales/order_email_items" template="email/order/items.phtml" order=$order}}*